# Call Block for specific number using webhook url twilio laravel

Tags: laravel, twilio, twilio-click-to-call

I am trying to create a blacklist. Anyone can tell me where i can store my blacklist number in twilio using call api. I am using webhook url for voice but i am stuck in blacklist number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted this for using Twilio Functions and Twilio Assets to host the Blacklist - [twilio Reject Incoming Calls with a Phone Number Blacklist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60065358/twilio-reject-incoming-calls-with-a-phone-number-blacklist)

Otherwise, you could something like Twilio Sync if you want to use your own code.