# Twilio Function Google Cloud Platform Credentials

Tags: google-cloud-platform, twilio

I'm trying to set up the `gcp` credentials for a Twilio Function.
Unfortunately it looks like I can only setup `env` variables but not reference a `json` file as we need to do it for GCP. 
Did anyone manage to set up GCP credentials from a Twilio Function?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A Twilio Function can parse a Twilio Asset file which contains JSON, there is an example of this below.

[twilio Reject Incoming Calls with a Phone Number Blacklist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60065358/twilio-reject-incoming-calls-with-a-phone-number-blacklist/60067422#60067422)

```
const fs = require('fs');

exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
    let fileName = 'blacklist.json';
    let file = Runtime.getAssets()[fileName].path;
    let text = fs.readFileSync(file);
    let blacklist = JSON.parse(text);
    console.log(blacklist);
    ...
```