# How should I make a function that changes the {{trigger.message.From}} to a name?

Tags: javascript, twilio

I'm busy with a project where a batch of automated SMS modules of fire alarm systems send their error messages to a phone number from Twilio.

Twilio parses the message to a Discord-channel through webhooks.

This is all working fine, but I have a variable '{{trigger.message.From}}' in Twilio which is the phone number from where the message is sent from. The goal is to make a JavaScript-function which replaces this variable with the corresponding name.

I tried a lot of scripts, but none of them ended up working.
What would be the best way to get this to work?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need some type of lookup table. You would need to store this lookup table in some persistent storage that Studio can refernece (say Run Function Widget or HTTP Request Widget).

This could be host on [Twilio Assets](https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/assets), say having a .json file mapping From number to location name, or similar using a tool like [Twilio Sync](https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/quickstart/serverless-functions-use-twilio-sync-to-create-read-update-delete-persistent-data) or [Airtable](https://www.twilio.com/blog/writing-airtable-sms).

Many ways. Below is an example of using a Twilio Assets to handle a Blocklist that may be useful to look at, to see how an Asset can be used from a Twilio Function.

[twilio Reject Incoming Calls with a Phone Number Blacklist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60065358/twilio-reject-incoming-calls-with-a-phone-number-blacklist)